# problem when using data from database to display in react

Tags: reactjs, database, fetch

I have data from API and I using state to store data in array ,the problem when I used this value ,, it's had errors and not show in pages ,

```
import React,{ useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import './PersonDataDetails.css';
import Axios from "axios";


const PersonDataDetails = () => {
    const [values, setValues] = useState([]);
   
    useEffect (()=> {
            const personalDataf = async ()=> {
            const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/personalData");
            const getdata = await res.json();
            setValues(getdata);
            console.log(getdata)
        }
        
            
        personalDataf()
    }, []);

        
            
        
       
return (

    
    <div className='PersonDataDetails'>
    <form className="form-PersonDataDetails">
        <div className="personal-data">
               { value[0].email }   
            </div>
            <input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder={values[0].username} className="input" />
            </form>
        </div>
)
```

and
this error what I have
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFjNc.png)

and when I remove values it's working like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoSyO.png)

so how can I call values after return and put them in div?

Comment: There is a typo in your code `{ value[0].email }` You have defined `values` in `const [values, setValues] = useState([]);` and not `value` Please rectify it. I suggest using plugin tools like prettier and lint to catch these errors

Comment: you can make use of optional chaining - `{ values[0]?.email }` and `{values[0]?.username}` so it returns `undefined` when there is no property found / unavailable

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so it returns `undefined` till the properties are available which wouldn't throw an error.

> Ideally considering a loading state is a better option here ..

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./PersonDataDetails.css";
import Axios from "axios";

const PersonDataDetails = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const personalDataf = async () => {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/personalData");
      const getdata = await res.json();
      setValues(getdata);
      console.log(getdata);
    };

    personalDataf();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="PersonDataDetails">
      <form className="form-PersonDataDetails">
        <div className="personal-data">{values[0]?.email}</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder={values[0]?.username}
          className="input"
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

or checking the `length` of array in state before rendering as

```
 return (
    values.length > 0 ? 
    (<div className="PersonDataDetails">
      <form className="form-PersonDataDetails">
        <div className="personal-data">{values[0]?.email}</div>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="firstName"
          placeholder={values[0]?.username}
          className="input"
        />
      </form>
    </div>) : null
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,,it's work like {values[0]?.username}